# Need to understand why: random missing required keys: [:id] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Friendship:

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

and User Model:

```
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

User Controller:

```
 @user = User.find_by!(username: params[:username])
 @user_following = @user.friends.all
 @user_followers = @user.inverse_friends.all
```

Say User A added as friend User B

Then User A Added as friend User C

User B view User A

```
Adding and Destroying friendships works.
```

I'm getting an error can anyone explain why this is happening?
errors goes away when User B add user C

It points out to this action:

```
<%= button_to "following", friendship_path(current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id:following.id)), method: :delete %>
```

> No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"friendships",
>   :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just no friendship has been found. My proposal is to handle this case with something like:

```
<% if friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by(friend_id: following.id) %>
  <%= button_to "following", friendship_path(friendship), method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= "No friendship found" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hey mate, thanks for the info. The problem seems to go away, but need more testing. ill accept your answer. thanks